# Why does it say “of Puvah, the clan of the Punites“?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, pinchas, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

In Bamidbar (26:23):

> בְּנֵ֤י יִשָּׂשכָר֙ לְמִשְׁפְּחֹתָ֔ם תּוֹלָ֕ע מִשְׁפַּ֖חַת הַתּוֹלָעִ֑י לְפֻוָ֕ה מִשְׁפַּ֖חַת הַפּוּנִֽי׃
>
> Descendants of Issachar by their clans: [Of] Tola, the clan of the Tolaites; of Puvah, the clan of the Punites;

The Puvah family is brought as a son of yisachar, but when it says the clan name it says “clan of Punites”, not “clan of Puvites”! Why?

(Note: Onkelos has both Puni and Puvah, according to the Chumash in front of me)

Comment: The Heh of פוה and the Ni of פוני are suffixes, leaving "פו" as the root of the surname. You can read it as **משפחת הפווני** - Puvani as V and U are interchangeable in Hebrew.

Comment: @Al Berko where is U interchanged with V in tana”ch Hebrew? Also, here the ה would have to be interchangeable with the ני as that is what has changed, not the U (I assume you mean וּ?)

Comment: @LoAni תוך שור און שוק all have consonantal ו switch to matres lectionis in different conjugations. (You probably never would have thought to ask this if you didn't regularly lisp your /w/ sounds into /v/ sounds as in many modern Germanic languages. Towkh and Tawekh actually sound similar.)

Comment: THat's like Torah - Torani

Comment: FWIW, I always thought it was a Second Temple-era copyist's error, like the skipping of the Nahash intro in I Samuel 11. A square(but not 1st Temple-era Paleo) nun looks lots like a vav if the bottom stroke is small or disconnected.

Comment: Note in divrei hayamin his name is פואה further confirming the lack of V sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **[Chida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai)** (1724—1806) writes [in his commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.26.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Chomat_Anakh_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.26.23.1&lang2=bi) to Numbers 26:23:

> **לפוה משפחת הפוני**. לכאורה הול״ל הפווי. ויש לרמוז כי הפוני רמז ה׳ שהיא מלכות פ״ו גימטריא אלהים נ׳ רמז לן׳ שערי בינה י׳ חכמה ודוק כי קצרתי
>
> **Of Puvah, the clan of the Punites**. In reality it should have said "the Puvites." We can say the "Punites" is an allusion to Hashem's kingship:
>   "*pu*" (*pey vav*) is the gematria of *Elokim*,
>   "*nun*" is an allusion to the 50 gates of understanding
>   "*yud*" refers to wisdom
>
> ... I've abridged this, but dig deeper into this and you'll find more

However the **[Kitzur Ba'al Haturim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher)** (1269-1343) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.26.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Kitzur_Baal_Haturim_on_Numbers.26.23.1&lang2=bi) that the name change has to do with Yissachar's intensive Torah study:

> **לפוה משפחת הפוני** היה לו לומר הפוי וכתיב פוני לומר שכל ישראל פונים אליו ללמוד מתורתו
>
> It should have written the "Puvites" but it says "Punites" to teach that all of Klal Yisrael would turn to face them to learn Torah.